# I want to hide tabbar by TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating an app by React Native.
and I'm using React Navigation.
This is the current project.

but I want to open a modal from the bottom.
I want to hide the tab bar.
Please tell me how to do it.
https://github.com/obscure723/react-navigation-ios13

Current project screen:
[image: current project screen]

Answer (score 0):

This is controllable via the order and nesting of navigation stacks.

You currently have a structure like this:

```
- BottomTabNavigator
  - StackNavigator (with ModalPresentationIOS - ShopStack)
    - Home
    - ShopDetailStack
```

In order to hide the tabs behind the modal, you have to rearrange them:

```
- StackNavigator (with ModalPresentationIOS)
 - BottomTabNavigator
   - Stack Navigator (Shop Stack)
     - Home
 - ShopDetailStack
```

This basically means that your modal stack should contain the tab navigation, not the other way around. The detail screen (the screen from the modal) needs to be declared as a sibling to the tab navigator)